# display: -webkit-box; property disappear few seconds after loading to the browser

Tags: html, css

I'm using multi line ellipsis concept for ending the text with dots when exceeds 2 rows. I'm using "display: -webkit-box;" property and it disappears in few seconds after loading to the browser. then the ellipsis property is not there anymore. please refer the image.

[image]/i.stack.imgur.com/uwqcb.png

any comments on this ?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: the issue is there in all browsers (chrome, firefox and ie)

Answer (score 0):

What web browser do you use? 
Webkit just running on webkit browser, try this one at your class ul for the wrapping:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: box;
```